# C# Spooky Action at a Distance --Value type changes in await block?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, race-condition, godot

I am fairly new to writing a non-trivial project in C# (used on Godot 4 platform), but not to programming in general.
I have the following snippets:

```cs
public async Task RequestAcknowledgementEvent(uint eventId)
    {
        Log($"Waiting for acknowledgement of event {eventId}");
        //read from the channel until it yields an event with this id
        await foreach (var e in serverEventsInFlightChannel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
        {
            Log($"Wait for ack of evnt {eventId}");
            Log("Got event from channel " + e);
            if (e != eventId) continue;
            Log($"Event {e} acked");
            return;
        }
    }
```

And this function is being called here:

```cs
 private async Task SendCountedClientEvent(
        ClientEvent clientEvent)
    {
        if (clientStream is null)
        {
            Log("Client is null", LogLevel.Error);
            return;
        }

        var eid = Interlocked.Increment(ref _eventCounter) - 1;
        clientEvent.EventId = eid;
        //send event to server
        GD.Print("Send event to server" + clientEvent);
        clientStream.RequestStream.WriteAsync(clientEvent).Wait();
        //wait for acknowledgement
        await RequestAcknowledgementEvent(clientEvent.EventId);
        Log("Event " + clientEvent.EventId + " acknowledged");
    }
```

Fairly simple stuff--send a request to the server, and wait for the server to return when it has finished this particular request (the traffic is being sent through a grpc stream).
When the client receives the acknowledgement event from the server:

```cs
case ServerEvent.EventOneofCase.Acknowledge:
 var ack = serverEvent.Acknowledge!;
 //see if there's any client event that server acknowledged
 Log("Got acknowledge event with id " + ack.EventId);
 await serverEventsInFlightChannel.Writer.WriteAsync(ack.EventId);
 Log("Wrote event " + ack.EventId + " to channel");
```

The `serverEventsInFlightChannel` is a C# `Channel` of `uint`'s.

The truly confusing issue I am encountering is that the value of `eventId` at the beginning of `RequestAcknowledgementEvent` (the first log message in that function) is one greater than the value of eventId within the await block (the second log message in the function). This should not be possible, structurally? `uint` should be cloned into the function and there is no way for anyone, even across threads, to mutate it, right?
You can't event hand out mutable references to value types, if I am not mistaken!
I am assuming the await block has something to do with it?

Does anyone know how this might be happening (and how I might resolve it)?
I am quite perplexed.

Comment: `clientStream.RequestStream.WriteAsync(clientEvent).Wait()` - why that instead of `await clientStream.RequestStream.WriteAsync(clientEvent)`? It's also not clear what log messages you are talking about, can you show the log?

Comment: `RequestAcknowledgementEvent` is an async method, so I'm guessing you have multiple requests to different `eventId` that are waiting asynchronously, so those log messages that you have will not necessarily post in the correct order when they are separated by an await call. I'm just guessing here because it's not entirely clear what your issue is.

Comment: @TJRockefeller By debugging, I can confirm this is not the case. If you step through the code. When I do step through, the moment I get to the call in the await foreach, the value changes compared to the initial value passed in to the RequestAcknowledgement function. My question is why this would be? eventId is just a cloned int, and is not modified anywhere within this function.

Comment: @GSerg the "Log{$"bla blah") lines are the log message I was talking about

Comment: When debugging async code there can be some odd behavior especially if things are multi threaded and you have code in different spots waiting asynchronously. Just because you are stepping in the code does not mean that you are staying on the same thread.

Comment: I should clarify because asynchronous does not mean multithreaded and really has very little to do with multi threading, so you may be staying on the same "thread", but you may be continuing work that was awaiting previously and is unrelated to the initial code that you broke execution on.

Comment: @TJRockefeller Yes, but my question is how is eventId changing at all, even under multithreaded contexts? There is no outlying reference to this value (there can't be, to my understanding, since it's a value type) and at no point in the function do I mutate the value.

Comment: Have you replaced the `.Wait()` with `await`, in that place and in all other places in the entire affected execution chain?

Comment: That shouldn't be relevant? The Wait() just blocks until the function completes. I've tried for completeness and the issue persists.

Comment: You will be surprised how often it is relevant.

Comment: Does your ack message have its *own* id that is separate from the acknowledged event id?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question . The client sends an event with a client-side unique id (just an 'atomic' increasing uint currently) with every request. Once the server finishes that particular request, it will send an acknowledgement event with the same id to the client.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public async Task RequestAcknowledgementEvent(uint eventId)
{
    Log($"Waiting for acknowledgement of event {eventId}");
    //read from the channel until it yields an event with this id
    await foreach (var e in serverEventsInFlightChannel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
    {
        Log($"Wait for ack of evnt {eventId}");
        Log("Got event from channel " + e);
        if (e != eventId) continue;
        Log($"Event {e} acked");
        return;
    }
}
```

When you get to the line `await foreach (var e in serverEventsInFlightChannel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())` the thread that was executing this function is returned to the calling function and is free to do other work. If it's the UI thread it can carry on doing UI things, or if it's a thread pool thread, then it is returned to the thread pool and can do other work. So let's say that someone called this method with eventId 10, so then you get a log saying "Waiting for acknowledgement of event 10" but when it gets to the await, the thread is freed to do other work while a response is awaited. While it is being awaited, maybe a different caller calls this method with eventId 11, so you get another "Waiting for acknowledgement of event 11" and maybe this is where you hit your break point, so eventId is showing 11, but then you step in the debugger thinking you will go into the foreach block and are expecting "Wait for ack of evnt 11", but really the calling thread for 11 is freed to do other work while it awaits a response, but the response for the call earlier to eventId 10 is ready, so instead of continuing in the context of the call to eventId 11 you are continuing in the context of the call earlier to eventId 10. You think you are still in the same method call, but you really are not in the same method call even though you took a "single step" in the debugger.

Something else to keep in mind is that when using `await foreach` that you are not awaiting a collection of items, and you only await once. Instead, you are awaiting each item in the collection. Each time you iterate your foreach block you are awaiting the next item in the enumeration, so the context can get mixed up every time you loop through your foreach block. When I say that the context can get mixed up I mean that you can have several contexts all calling that same foreach block at the same time and the order is not guaranteed for the contexts to execute.

Comment: Currently, I only make one request. And even if there were multiple, it should say "Wait for ack of evnt 10" as well as "Waiting for ack of evnt 11"--but this is not what's happening. It *only* logs "Waiting for acknowledgement of event 10" and then "Wait for ack of evnt 11". No other messages are logged.

Comment: @kaifas I would recommend working on boiling your code down to something that can reproduce this problem because the code you have shown can't reproduce the problem, and you won't get good answers until other people can reproduce the same problem in their own environment.